# When will ranges be included in the c++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++14

I could find two proposals to include ranges in C++:
[N1871](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1871.html) is fairly old (2005), and [N3513](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3513.html)

However I could not find anything about ranges in the current C++14 draft (N3690). Does this mean that it will not be part of C++14? If that is the case, why is it so cumbersome to introduce ranges?

Comment: Just guessing, but probably because we already have iterator pairs it's considered low priority.

Comment: If you go through the Ranges mailing list archive at http://www.open-std.org/pipermail/ranges/ you can see that 1) Not a lot is happening right now, and 2) No one could really agree on anything. Also, if you look at the post-Bristol mailing, you can see there's nothing relevant: http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/post-bristol-standards-papers-mailing-available So no, not going to happen for C++14.

Comment: "*why is it so cumbersome to introduce ranges?*" Because nobody really knows what ranges are, should mean, and such. The Ranges SG seems to be divided into the Boost.Range camp and a camp that believes that Ranges should be fundamental objects (aka: the D.Range camp), rather than being little more than pairs of specialized iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that it will not be part of C++14?

Yes, indeed it will not be part of C++14. Unfortunately, nobody cared enough to work on a proposal.

> If that is the case, why is it so cumbersome to introduce ranges?

Hard to tell. Sometimes the reason is that different people have different expectations on what should be standardized and how (see modules or concepts), and sometimes it is just because the feature is more complex to formalize than urgent.

Also, what most often happens is that Boost libraries are taken as an experimental, proto-standard implementation; and while there was enough experience and common consensus on libraries such as Boost.Thread, Boost.Function, and Boost.Bind - so they got standardized quite smoothly - not everybody is satisfied with Boost.Range, mostly because of its lack of an extensive, high-level support for functional programming.

Comment: "*lack of an extensive, high-level support for functional programming.*" Which would look like what, exactly?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Something like Haskell.

Comment: And why would we want C++ to look like Haskell? Also, [people did submit proposals on elements of ranges](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3686.html).

Comment: @NicolBolas: Many of us _don't_, and I shall refer you back to the statement "different people have different expectations"

Comment: @NicolBolas: I guess, because it is expressive and powerful - and due to lazy evaluation, reasonably efficient. Notice, that this does not necessarily reflect my *own* point of view. I'm just trying to figure why ranges did not get into C++14. Thank you for the link, I did not know about it.